# Is it possible to create a temporary table from a select query AND add a set of extra columns at the same time?

Tags: mysql

I want to create a temporary table in one line using 3 columns + content from a existing table called `affiliateproduct` and at the same time add 2 columns `title` and `content` to the temporary table. Both need to be of type VARCHAR, however i cannot define these 2 columns explicitly in the same query. As a workaround i did the following:

```
       CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE affiliate_product_results ENGINE = MEMORY SELECT ap.id,
           ap.affiliateImageUrl, ap.rank, "" AS title, "" AS content FROM affiliateproduct ap;
```

This results in a table that includes the 3 columns from affiliateproduct with corresponding types, but title and content both get the type `char(0)` assigned. That is not the type that i want. (It should be `varchar(255)` instead). Is there a way to get this to work with the correct type assignment? (I know i could probably assign a value of `"     "`  or something and then it would become a varchar(n spaces) but thats rather hacky.

Is there a way or am i forced to do an extra column insert query after the temporary table creation.

Thank you.

EDIT: I found a way to do it but its hacky. It goes like this:

```
       CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE affiliate_product_results ENGINE = MEMORY SELECT ap.id,
           ap.affiliateImageUrl, ap.rank, ap.affiliateImageUrl AS title, ap.affiliateImageUrl AS content FROM affiliateproduct ap;
```

Now title and content get the same columntype as affiliateimageUrl (varchar255)

Comment: Does `CAST()` work to specify the type?

Comment: I did think of trying that one out but i was hoping there could be a more elegant way of defining the type, because i suspect it will do a `Cast()` call for every row from affiliateproduct (correct me if im wrong). I will try now if `Cast()` works :)

Comment: @Progman Cast() cannot cast to VARCHAR, only CHAR. see https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-cast/

Answer (score 1):

You can get a `VARCHAR` column using [`SPACE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_space) with [`TRIM`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_trim):

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE affiliate_product_results ENGINE = MEMORY 
SELECT ap.id, ap.affiliateImageUrl, ap.rank, 
  TRIM(SPACE(255)) AS title, 
  TRIM(SPACE(255)) AS content
FROM affiliateproduct
```

In case you want to initialize the new `VARCHAR` columns with `NULL`:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE affiliate_product_results ENGINE = MEMORY 
SELECT ap.id, ap.affiliateImageUrl, ap.rank, 
  IF(TRIM(SPACE(255)) = '', NULL, TRIM(SPACE(255))) AS title, 
  IF(TRIM(SPACE(255)) = '', NULL, TRIM(SPACE(255))) AS content
FROM affiliateproduct
```

You can adjust the size of the `VARCHAR` column with the parameter on `SPACE`.

[**demo on dbfiddle.uk**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=64b2d099bb981ff0738ae8fae3b90eab)

Comment: hehe, nice solution :) But would this be as fast as simply using ADD column?

Comment: using columns as reference is perhaps faster but you also insert the values of these columns to the temporary table. There also can be a situation where the table has no varchar column.